# GCP: Why do 2 different instances in 2 different projects share the same file system?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filesystems, google-compute-engine

I'm new to GCP.

I've created 2 projects. In each project, I created a compute engine VM instance. The instances have different names but are located in the same region and loc.

When I go into gcloud shell and connect to 1 of my projects, I see the files in that instance that I created in the other instance in the other project.

I would have thought that the 2 projects would not share the same filesystem. Am I mistaken? Is this the default behavior if I create the instances in the same region and zone?

I connect to my projects by opening a gcloud shell and using the “gcloud config [priject-id]” command.

Is there a way to create instances in different projects that do not share the same filesystem?

Comment: If you create a file in one of them, this file appears in the other?

Comment: You probably logged into the same VM from both cloud shells. Try logging in directly from your workstation.

Comment: From the terminal, I login using: "gcloud config set project my-project-python-005". I close that terminal and open a new one and login using: "gcloud config set project my-project-tutorial-005". These are 2 separate projects using 2 different VMs, yet I see the same filesystem. Could it be how I set up the VM instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is not possible for two instances to share the same file system.

You can attach the same disk to two different VM's but not at the same time. In order to [attach the disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) (containing mentioned filesystem) to another machine first you need to [detach it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) from the current one.

**You'r impression of a "shared" filesystem must be false and you got confused (logged in twice to the same machine).**

But - assuming there's some but (which may never be ruled out completely) you can check which disk is attached to which VM by running these commands in the cloud shell:

```
gcloud config set project my-project-name-1
gcloud compute instances describe instance1 | grep disk
```

Your output should be something similar:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ gcloud compute instances describe instaince111 | grep disk
Did you mean zone [europe-west4-b] for instance: [log1] (Y/n)?  n

No zone specified. Using zone [europe-west3-c] for instance: [instance111].
disks:
  diskSizeGb: '10'
  source: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxx/zones/europe-west3-c/disks/isntance111
```

Then select another project and run the [describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) command again.

**----- UPDATE ------**

Cloud shell is your personam VM that doesn't belong to any of the projects and is not in your default VPC. It's just created and preconfigured with `gcloud` for your convinience. If you want to log in to specific VM it's best to use `SSH` button next to the VM specs in the cloud console vm list or `[gcloud compute ssh][3]` command.

If you just select another project in your cloud shell VM you're still logged in to this VM and it only tells `gcloud` utility that any commands issued after `gcloud config set project my-proj-name` will affect the project `my-proj-name`.

Comment: I used cloud shell. For project my-project-python-005, the output was:
diskSizeGb: '10'
 source: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-python-005/zones/us-east1-b/disks/my-python-instance-1

For project my-project-tutorial-005, the output was:
diskSizeGb: '10'
 source: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-tutorial-005/zones/us-central1-a/disks/my-tutorial-instance-1

I touch a file, XYZ, in my y-project-tutorial-005. I exited the shell and opened a shell for my-project-python-005. When I issued the command "ls", the file XYZ was there, too,.

Comment: Can you provide exact commands you used and their output ? Please update your question with those details.

Comment: GCP Commands  

On a Chromebook: Opened cloudshell  
Issued command:  joei0005@cloudshell:~$ gcloud config set project my-project-tutorial-005
Output:  Updated property [core/project  ].
Issued command:  Touch ABC  
Exited cloudshell by quitting window  

Opened cloudshell  
Issued command:   joei0005@cloudshell:~$ gcloud config set project my-project-python-005
Output:  Updated property [core/project].
Issued commend:  joei0005@cloudshell:~ (my-project-python-005)$ ls
Output:  ABC README-cloudshell.txt

Comment: Cloud shell is just your personal machine (separate from your VM's in your projects) and doesn't belong to any of them. Have a look at the [Cloud Shell Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs).

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I reviewed the documentation in the link you provided. It cleared some things up for me. Should I use the SSH dropdown for the instance to connect to the individual VM instances?

Comment: Using the `SSH` button is the easies way to login to your VM's and I use this way all the time. If you think my comment helped please accept my answer :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. It's extremely helpful. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include what was resolved in the comments - please accept the answer by clicking green checkmark beside the answer. Thank you !